# Force reinstall of all chocolatey packages after profile "migration"

Tags: windows-10, restore, reinstall, chocolatey

For various reasons, my Windows user profile has been recreated; and - AppData files have been copied into the new profile, but not registry contents.

Now, I'm trying to restore the installation state of my chocolatey-installed apps. The thing is, when I try to `choco install foo`, I get a message saying:

```
foo v1.2.3 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.
```

How can I force a reinstall of all installed apps?

Comment: @vssher - You should submit a detailed answer instead of submitting a temporary comment.

Comment: @vssher: That doesn't reinstall anything.

Answer (score 6):

It seems this should work:

```
choco upgrade all --force
```

... and remember to execute this in a Powershell opened with "Run As Administrator".

**Edit:** If any of the installations fail (which occasionally happens ), I don't know how to continue with just the remaining re-installations rather than *all* of it together. So, more robust solutions would be very welcome.